# Rails strong parameters, user require and get an hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have this method

```
def create_billing_address(data)
    address_data = data.permit(:first_name,
                                :last_name,
                                :phone,
                                :address_1,
                                :city,
                                :postcode,
                                :country)
    service_customer.create_address(customer_id, address_data)
end
```

But now I want to check that all the keys are present. I tried to do this

```
address_data = data.require(:first_name,
                            :last_name,
                            :phone,
                            :address_1,
                            :city,
                            :postcode,
                            :country)
```

But require return an array instead of an hash.

How can I do to have the same behaviour of `permit` but with `require` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is only intended to ensure that the params have the correct general structure.

For example if you have:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, :baz)
```

`require` lets us bail early if the `:foo` key is missing since we cant do anything with the request.

`require` is not intended to validate the presence of individual params - that is handled with model level validations in Rails.

If you really had to you could do:

```
def create_billing_address!(data)
  keys = [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :address_1, :city, :postcode, :country]

 keys.each do |k|
    raise ActionController::ParameterMissing and return unless data[k].present?
 end

 service_customer.create_address(customer_id, data.permit(*keys))
end
```

But thats just bad application design as you're letting the model level business logic creep into the controller.

Answer (score 2):

`permit` and `require` are not interchangeable the way you think.  If you establish that all the required keys are present, they *still* need to be permitted to be used in a mass assignment.

So you'd likely need to do...

```
def create_billing_address(data)
  fields = %i(first_name last_name phone address_1 city postcode country)
  address_data = data.permit(data.require(fields))
  service_customer.create_address(customer_id, address_data)
end
```

The `data.require` will raise an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception if a key is missing, if not it will return the array of keys which can be used by `permit`.

Generally, what you want to do with `require` is more typically handled by model validation.

Documentation on require and permit is here...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html